# Определить число элементов в обернутом наборе

Tags: jquery

Не могу понять, почему не срабатывает скрипт, который должен определить число элементов в обернутом наборе и вывести значение в определенный див?
http://jsfiddle.net/t9Uyd/16/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли в скобки обернуть document: $(document).ready(...

и вообще на jsfiddle это делать не обязательно, там слева есть опции onLoad и onDomready.

Comment: От оно чё... а я уже такие http://jsfiddle.net/t9Uyd/22/ скрипты пишу... спасибо